# $BMO$ is not reflexive

Tags: duality, hardy-spaces

It is well known that $BMO$ is the dual space of the Hardy space $H^1$, which is the dual space of $VMO$. I believe that $BMO$ is not reflexive, but I am not quite sure that the above information is enough to obtain that non-reflexivity.

Comment: This shows that $VMO$ is not reflexive, and a Banach space is reflexive if and only if its dual is. Applying this twice shows that $BMO$ (and $H^1$) are not reflexive either. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152343/a-banach-space-is-reflexive-if-and-only-if-its-dual-is-reflexive